# "sorry ubuntu 20.04 experienced an internal error" what does this message mean?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to know what are the causes that this message keep showing

> sorry ubuntu 20.04 experienced an internal error

I start using Ubuntu for less than week now and i get this message twice
I tried this in the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt get-upgrade
```

and i restart my computer but it does not seem to solve the problem

can anyone help me and how i should deal with message in the future

thanks :)

Comment: Where does this message appear (in the console, in a pop-up window, somewhere else), and under what circumstances?

Comment: in a pop-up window

Answer (score 1):

If you need to help the Ubuntu developer you can send the bug report, you can click on report problem.

The crash report are located under `/var/crash`, you can empty the directory then reboot:

```
sudo rm  /var/crash/*
```

If the problem still persist you can disable Apport program (it is not recommended):

```
 sudo systemctl disable --now apport.service
```